# AWS EC2 : Change SSH default port in inbound rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

In EC2 AWS inbound rules, I would like to allow another port than 22 as default SSH connection.
But the port field seems not writable :

[image]

Any idea how to unlock the field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inbound rules you can choose Custom TCP and then set the port number.
[image]